# One line is being skipped in file with isalpha()

Tags: c, ctype

I am using isalpha() to determine if there are characters on the line and it is showing that the line "90 1 0" contains alphabetic characters.

Here is the relevant code

```
bool digitTest(char *test, int arysize)
{
int i;
for (i =0; i<arysize; i++)
{
    if ((isalpha(test[i])) != 0){

        return 0;
    }

    if (i==arysize)
        return 1;
            i++;
}
return 1;
}
```

It is called here

```
char buffer[4096] = {};

while(NULL!=fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)){
    if (digitTest(buffer, 4096) == 0){

        printf ("contains alpha\n");
        continue;
    /*printing code if there is no alphabetic characters below, i do not believe it is  relevant*/
```

and this is output

```
1
1
1
contains alpha 
contains alpha
contains alpha 
25123.90
54321.23
6
```

and input

```
1
1
1
89 23.5 not a number
90 1 0
-5.25 not a number 10000
25123.90 54321.23 6
```

Comment: Have you checked in a debugger which lines are passed and what they contain?

Comment: are you not looping past the end of your buffer by passing in 4096 to test function? it might be accessing memory where there is a valid char

Comment: @bash.d I do not know how to do that sorry.

Comment: @75inchpianist should I just make the buffer bigger?

Comment: no, you should check the whole buffer, or the buffer up til you hit a terminating null character. Whichever comes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Looks like you might be accessing locations in memory that contain characters, Change your code to

```
char buffer[4096] = {};
memset(buffer, 0, 4096);

while(NULL!=fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)){
if (digitTest(buffer, strlen(buffer)) == 0){ //get actual length of buffer

    printf ("contains alpha\n");
    continue;
```

**EDIT**

In order to make your code not respond to either `\n` or `\r` do

```
bool digitTest(char *test, int arysize)
{
int i;
for (i =0; i<arysize; i++)
{
    if( test[i] == '\r' || test[i] == '\n')
        return 1;
    if ((isalpha(test[i])) != 0){

        return 0;
    }

    if (i==arysize)
        return 1;

}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: This will fail as `fgets()` reads the new-line character into `buffer`.

Comment: @hmjd you mean after `\0`?

Comment: Nope, before the `\0`. `fgets()` includes the newline character in the buffer it is populating.

Comment: Okay, but neither `\n` nor `\r` are displayable, so what is wrong?

Comment: Neither `\r` or `\n` are [`isalpha()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha).

Comment: No, I don't think so... Their corresponding values are `0xD` and `0xA`, respectively... They are out of the displayable range

Comment: So, `0` usually means `false`... See [this](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) here

Comment: Exactly, so the `digitTest()` will fail when it should not.

Comment: @hmjd I added a few lines... Will serve the purpose, although it is not very "beautiful"

Comment: The function name is confusing I think, as it implies it must be digits only. But it actually is not alpha.

Answer (score 4):

The code has a few problems:

- You shouldn't check all buffer. Check buffer until `\0`. because the output of `fgets` is a C-style string.
- Second problem is an extra `i++` in function `digitTest`. You should remove it.
- You don't need `arysize` any more.

Use this `digitTest` function instead

```
int digitTest(char *test)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; test[i] && test[i] != '\n'; i++)
  {
     if (isalpha(test[i]) != 0)
        return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

*(maybe has minor bugs, I didn't test it)*

And call it like this:

```
while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) ) {
    if (!digitTest(buffer)) {
        printf ("contains alpha\n");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest stopping processing when `\n` is also encountered as `fgets()` will add this to the buffer it is populating (and `arysize` is no longer required).